# Validate folder name

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a folder name in c#.

I have tried the following regex :

```
 ^(.*?/|.*?\\)?([^\./|^\.\\]+)(?:\.([^\\]*)|)$
```

but it fails and I also tried using `GetInvalidPathChars()`.

It fails when i try using `P:\abc` as a folder name i.e `Driveletter:\foldername`

Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: So can a regex validate drive letter+ foldername

Comment: Question: In what situation is a user going to have to manually type a path so specific you have to regex it?

Comment: In Windows, certain 'device names' are reserved as well, like 'COM1' or 'AUX'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do that in this way (using `System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars` constant):

```
bool IsValidFilename(string testName)
{
    Regex containsABadCharacter = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars) + "]");
    if (containsABadCharacter.IsMatch(testName) { return false; };

    // other checks for UNC, drive-path format, etc

    return true;
}
```

**[edit]**
If you want a regular expression that validates a folder path, then you could use this one:

`Regex regex = new Regex("^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*]+)+\\\\?$");`

**[edit 2]**
I've remembered one tricky thing that lets you check if the path is correct:

`var invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars(path)`

or (for files):

`var invalidFileNameChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(fileName)`

Comment: this fails because it does take into account the drive letter

Comment: would this be the right way to do it                                            Regex sPattern = new Regex("^((([a-zA-Z]:)(\\{2}[a-zA-Z]+)(\\{2}\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))(?=(\\(\w[\w ]*)))(\\\w[\w ]*)*)$");
                
                if (!(sPattern.IsMatch(_mountpoint)))
                {

Comment: I used to think this is good enough, but its not. 1. Pictographs in Folder/Filename will break the create process on SOME windows versions. 2. See this page for invalid Foldernames like "COM1" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx 3. I'm not sure if using dots is safe in any way. Its not when manually creating files/folders (win7)

Answer (score 2):

Validating a folder name correctly can be quite a mission. See my blog post [*Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level - part 2*](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/taking-data-binding-validation-and-mvvm.html).
Don't be fooled by the title, it's about validating file system paths, and it illustrates some of the complexities involved in using the methods provided in the .Net framework. While you may want to use a regex, it isn't the most reliable way to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

this is regex you should use :

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^([a-zA-Z0-9][^*/><?\"|:]*)$");
if (!regex.IsMatch(txtFolderName.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Folder fail", "info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    metrotxtFolderName.Focus();
}
```