# Validate names for folders created using code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating folders based on the name given by the user in text box from code behind in asp.net. Now I want to validate the name entered by the user before creating the folder.
I want to validate the name on client side preferably (like using javascript or jquery).

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Did you look at the regular expression validator?

Comment: You dint specify what kind of validation you want. Allow numbers or not, hypens,... ?

Comment: I have tried Path.GetInvalidPathChars for server side validation. Looking for client side validation for better performance.

Comment: @Cdeez .. restricting user from entering invalid names for folders to be created.

Comment: Try the answers from this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688985/validate-folder-name-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* to do the check on server side and/or on client side too. For client side you may think about some simple *regular expression*, on server side you can use `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` and check if provided by user string contains any of them.

Remember only that on *client side* could be different OS es, so also a set of valid characters in file name can vary, so what you can do is just use only set valid for OS you use on *server side*.