# Regex for Windows Scheduled Task Process Name

Tags: regex

To whitelist a SIEM detection, I need to enter a regex for the below path:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
```

The only thing that varies in this instance is the username, so far I have tried the below with no luck so far:

```
[a-zA-Z]:[\\\/](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\\/])*([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.exe)
```

Comment: Are there any parts which stay constant, such as app name or drive letter, or is the whole thing variable? (As an aside, it doesn’t strike me as an *amazing* whitelist if the regex has to be so general.)

Comment: Apologies, should have made that clearer, the only thing that changes is the user name. I will update the main post.

Comment: Yup, so from a security point of view I’d keep as much static content as I could and only regex the username. Clearly you’ll need escapes for the backslashes and (iirc) the colon.

Answer (score 1):

A generic pattern to match any character other than a backslash is `[^\\]`.

Use

```
C:\\Users\\[^\\]+\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate\.exe
          ^^^^^^^^^
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lREE2H/1).

If you are going to be more restrictive, following the [Validate folder name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688985/), use `[^<>:\"/\\|?*]` instead of `[^\\]`

```
C:\\Users\\[^<>:\"/\\|?*]+\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate\.exe
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/lREE2H/2).